# Links do not work when an image is in the header HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Whenever I add an image to the header, suddenly all the links in both the header and the navbar stop working. I've been trying to fix it, but I only know a little bit about html so I'm getting stuck. Here is the HTML

```css
body { background-color: #abc67e;
      color: #666666;
      font-family:Tahoma; 
      height: 100%;
}     
header { background-color: #ffe4b5;
         color: #FFFFFF;
         font-family: Tahoma; 
         position: relative;
         margin-bottom: 0;}

h1 { line-height: 200%;
     background-image: url(sunset.jpg);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: right;
     padding-left: 20px;
     height: 72px;
     margin-bottom: 0;
}
nav { font-weight: bold;
      background-color: #deb887; 
}
h2 {  font-family: Tahoma; 
}
dt { color: #000033; 
     font-weight: bold;
}            
footer { font-size: 0.70em;
         text-align: center;
         font-style: italic;
         padding: 10px;
}        
h3 { color: #000033; 
}
main { padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
}
#wrapper { margin-left: auto;
           margin-right: auto;
           width: 55%;
           background-color: #fdf5e6;
           min-width: auto;
           box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #523411;
           height: 100%;
           border: 4px;
           border-style: outset;
}
nav ul { list-style-type: none; 
        margin-top: 0;
        z-index: 99;}
nav li { display: inline; }
footer ul { list-style-type: none; }
footer li { display: inline; }
footer a { text-decoration: none; padding-right: 10px; }
aside { float: right; 
      border-left: 1px;
      border-left-style: dotted;
      padding-left: 50px;}
aside img { width: 100%;
          height: 100%;}
section { float: right;
        width: 320px;}
.galleryul { list-style-type: none; }
.galleryli { display: inline-block;
     width: 225px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
     margin: 10px;
     background-color: #EAEAEA;
     text-align: center;
     font-style: italic;
     font-family: Tahoma; }
label { float: left; 
      display: block; 
      width: 8em;
      padding-right: 25px; 
      }
input { display: block;
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      }
textarea { display: block; 
        margin-bottom: 1em;
      }
#mySubmit { margin-left: 11.5em;
      }
.navbarimg { position: absolute; 
             padding-left: 650px;
             padding-top: 110px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <title>A Dog's Life</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
  <header>
      <img src="images/navimg.png" class="navbarimg">
      <a href="project/index.html"><img src="images/banner.jpg" style="width:100%"></a>
      <h3></h3>
  </header>
  <nav>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="/index.html"><img src="images/home-nav.png" alt="Home"></a></li>
      <li><a href="/about.html"><img src="images/about-nav.png" alt="About"></a></li>
      <li><a href="/services.html"><img src="images/services-nav.png" alt="Services"></a></li>
      <li><a href="/gallery.html"><img src="images/gallery-nav.png" alt="Gallery"></a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact.html"><img src="images/contact-nav.png" alt="Contact"></a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
      <h2>Reserve your dog's stay today!</h2>
      <aside><img src="images/dogs1.jpg" alt="Dogs playing"></aside>
      <h3>Contact Us</h3>
      <p>Required information is marked with an asterisk (*).</p>
      <form method="post" action="http://webdevbasics.net/scripts/pacific.php">
      <label for="myFName">*First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" required="required" name="myFName" id="myFName"><br>
      <label for="myLName">*Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" required="required" name="myLName" id="myLName"><br>
      <label for="myEmail">*Email:</label>
      <input type="email" required="required" name="myEmail" id="myEmail"><br>
      <label for="myPhone">Phone:</label>
      <input type="tel" name="myPhone" id="myPhone"><br>
      <label for="arrival">Arrival Date:</label>
      <input type="date" name="arrival" id="arrival">
      <label for="nights">Nights:</label>
      <input type="number" name="nights" min="1" max="14" id="nights">
      <label for="myComments">*Comments:</label>
      <textarea name="myComments" required="required" cols="20" rows="2" id="myComments"></textarea><br>
      <input type="submit" id="mySubmit" value="Submit">
      </form>
  <br>
  <img src="images/logo.png">
  </main>
  <footer>
  <br>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
  Copyright &copy; 2016 A Dog's Life<br>
  <a href="mailto:pierce@jensen.com">pierce@jensen.com</a>
  </footer>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: run the html through the w3c validator, look for syntax errors.

Comment: @A.Sharma That's a pretty definitive statement. Do you have anything to back that claim up? Images load perfectly fine within the `<header>` element anytime I've tried it. Images should not be referenced in the `<head>` section. Two completely different elements...

Comment: @A.Sharma that's a HTML5 header tag, not the HTML header

Comment: @A.Sharma You seem to be confusing `head` with `header`.

Comment: @Xufox brainfreeze. It's getting to be the end of the workday :)

Answer (score 1):

The header image is overlapping your Nav:

```
header {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<img>` tag in your header is actually overlaying on top of your links, rendering them inaccessible.

Try adjusting the [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) property accordingly :

```
.navbarimg {
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 650px;
    padding-top: 110px;
    /* This will "push" the <img> tag down below the <a> tags so they can be clicked */
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**Example Snippet**

```css
body { background-color: #abc67e;
      color: #666666;
      font-family:Tahoma; 
      height: 100%;
}     
header { background-color: #ffe4b5;
         color: #FFFFFF;
         font-family: Tahoma; 
         position: relative;
         margin-bottom: 0;}

h1 { line-height: 200%;
     background-image: url(sunset.jpg);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: right;
     padding-left: 20px;
     height: 72px;
     margin-bottom: 0;
}
nav { font-weight: bold;
      background-color: #deb887; 
}
h2 {  font-family: Tahoma; 
}
dt { color: #000033; 
     font-weight: bold;
}            
footer { font-size: 0.70em;
         text-align: center;
         font-style: italic;
         padding: 10px;
}        
h3 { color: #000033; 
}
main { padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
}
#wrapper { margin-left: auto;
           margin-right: auto;
           width: 55%;
           background-color: #fdf5e6;
           min-width: auto;
           box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #523411;
           height: 100%;
           border: 4px;
           border-style: outset;
}
nav ul { list-style-type: none; 
        margin-top: 0;
        z-index: 99;}
nav li { display: inline; }
footer ul { list-style-type: none; }
footer li { display: inline; }
footer a { text-decoration: none; padding-right: 10px; }
aside { float: right; 
      border-left: 1px;
      border-left-style: dotted;
      padding-left: 50px;}
aside img { width: 100%;
          height: 100%;}
section { float: right;
        width: 320px;}
.galleryul { list-style-type: none; }
.galleryli { display: inline-block;
     width: 225px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
     margin: 10px;
     background-color: #EAEAEA;
     text-align: center;
     font-style: italic;
     font-family: Tahoma; }
label { float: left; 
      display: block; 
      width: 8em;
      padding-right: 25px; 
      }
input { display: block;
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      }
textarea { display: block; 
        margin-bottom: 1em;
      }
#mySubmit { margin-left: 11.5em;
      }
.navbarimg { position: absolute; 
             padding-left: 650px;
             padding-top: 110px; z-index: -1;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>A Dog's Life</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <img src="images/navimg.png" class="navbarimg">
        <a href="project/index.html"><img src="images/banner.jpg" style="width:100%"></a>
        <h3></h3>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="/index.html"><img src="images/home-nav.png" alt="Home"></a></li>
        <li><a href="/about.html"><img src="images/about-nav.png" alt="About"></a></li>
        <li><a href="/services.html"><img src="images/services-nav.png" alt="Services"></a></li>
        <li><a href="/gallery.html"><img src="images/gallery-nav.png" alt="Gallery"></a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact.html"><img src="images/contact-nav.png" alt="Contact"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <h2>Reserve your dog's stay today!</h2>
        <aside><img src="images/dogs1.jpg" alt="Dogs playing"></aside>
        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
        <p>Required information is marked with an asterisk (*).</p>
        <form method="post" action="http://webdevbasics.net/scripts/pacific.php">
        <label for="myFName">*First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" required="required" name="myFName" id="myFName"><br>
        <label for="myLName">*Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" required="required" name="myLName" id="myLName"><br>
        <label for="myEmail">*Email:</label>
        <input type="email" required="required" name="myEmail" id="myEmail"><br>
        <label for="myPhone">Phone:</label>
        <input type="tel" name="myPhone" id="myPhone"><br>
        <label for="arrival">Arrival Date:</label>
        <input type="date" name="arrival" id="arrival">
        <label for="nights">Nights:</label>
        <input type="number" name="nights" min="1" max="14" id="nights">
        <label for="myComments">*Comments:</label>
        <textarea name="myComments" required="required" cols="20" rows="2" id="myComments"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" id="mySubmit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    <br>
    <img src="images/logo.png">
    </main>
    <footer>
    <br>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    Copyright &copy; 2016 A Dog's Life<br>
    <a href="mailto:pierce@jensen.com">pierce@jensen.com</a>
    </footer>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks. So how do I get the image to be above the header and navbar, but not get in the way of the links?

Answer (score 1):

You're positioning your image absolute within the .navbar definition, so it will be taken out of the document flow and automatically overlay everything not otherwise specified to be above with z-index. Either add a z-index to the other elements, or don't use absolute positioning to completely avoid the chance of this happening.

You also don't have to set a padding to the element (which will also overlay other elements even though it's invisible space because following the rules of the box model, it's "inside" the element), but work with left/top instead of padding-left/padding-top.